# cart with rpart not displaying entire plot

Tags: r, plot, classification, rpart

I am trying to plot a classification tree using rpart, and R isn't including all of my variables. I have 20 cases, and 200 variables. My data looks something like this:

```
data <- data.frame(y = c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 10)), x1 = c(rnorm(20)), x2 = c(rnorm(20)+0.5), x3 = c(rnorm(20)-0.2))
```

but with x1 + x2 +x3 .... + x200.

All of my variable values are similar to this; very small, some even averaging around 0.0005.I need a classification tree, and my y is binary, so I want method = "class" :

```
cart <- rpart(formula = y ~ ., data = data, method = "class")
```

When I type

```
print(cart)
```

I get:

```
n= 20
node), split, n, deviance, yval 
* denotes terminal node
1) root 20 5.958333 0.4583333  
2) x50< 0.0005126315 16 2.437500 0.1875000 *
3) x50>=0.0005126315 8 0.000000 1.0000000 *
```

I'm not sure why it's only splitting according to x50. I tried plotting it to see what was going on, and when I did

```
plot(cart)
```

I got the following plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZOFN.png

Any idea what's going on, or how I can fix this? Much appreciated.

Comment: this is in the examples of `?rpart`, ie, `text(cart, use.n = TRUE)`

Comment: @rawr, use.n in text() tells plot() to include the variable names of each node. My issue goes further than that--not only are the nodes absent from the graph, they are excluded from the analysis (see above, where I wrote the output for plot(cart)

Comment: have you read the breiman paper about regression trees?

Comment: @rawr no, but I just looked online. do you mean the 1984 book? do you think it would be helpful for this?

Comment: I think it would explain why you are only getting one split. Are you expecting more just because you have more variables? that's not really how these methods work

Comment: @rawr I am expecting more than one split because I ran a t-test on each pair of outcomes for each variable and got that several other variables were more significant than x50, so it doesn't make sense to me why R would only select one less significant variable to split. Which is why I think this is an issue in my code, not my interpretation. i could be wrong, I'll check out the book regardless

Comment: have you also tried ctree in the party package? that may give you closer to what you expect. there is a good explanation [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12140/conditional-inference-trees-vs-traditional-decision-trees), but for more indepth, you might get some papers